# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise - cannot launch Node.js Interactive Window

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2017

I have an issue with NodeJS development in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. When I try to open the NodeJS Interactive Window, I get an error message window like the following:

[image]

I have tried to uninstall and re-install Node.js tools with the Visual Studio 2017 installer - to no avail. I can see the Node.js templates in the Project Template section, and I can also create new Node.js projects - but the Interactive Window is unavailable, and I continue receiving the illustrated error message.

I hope there is someone who can help with this issue. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I found a workaround (sort of), which was a little weird; I ran the Repair of Visual Studio 2017 - that didn't help. Then I ran the Repair a *second* time - and now it seems to work(!) I can open the Interactive Window without any problems.

Wondering why it required TWO repairs; anyway, hope that it can be of help to somebody else.